# Compressing numeric string ids using BCD in C

Tags: c, compression, bcd

I have a bunch of ids in the form of `uint32_t-uint32_t`two unsigned integers separated by a hyphen. I'm looking to compress them. I was thinking to convert them to BCD (in other words two digits per byte) and output the compressed string. For example, `90-1418`

```
90-1418 -> 0x39 0x00 0x2d 0x31 0x34 0x31 0x38
             \    /    |    \    /    \    /
              0x90    0x2d   0x14      0x18
```

Are there any libraries in C out there that can compress/decompress this type of strings?

Comment: Why not just replace the uint32s with smaller binary types that can accommodate your range of values?

Comment: @500, That would not be optimal if the numbers are usually small, but sometimes large.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the number as `( ( num1 * factor ) + num2 ) * 16 + factor`.

```
001011000101010110100111
\/\_________/\_____/\__/
 \          \      \   \___ The number of bits in first number (without leading zeros), padded to 4 bits.
  \          \      \______ The first number in big-endian byte order.
   \          \____________ The second number in big-endian byte order.
    \______________________ Padding so the whole takes a multiple of 8 bits.
```

3 bytes.

Max = 32+4+32+4 = 9 bytes.

This always produces a shorter result than yours.

Comment: This is interesting. So basically I strip the hyphen and store the binary string in 3 bytes.  Is this a specific algorithm? and do you know if there is a library implementing this?

Comment: You know how 345 = ( ( 3 * 10 ) + 4 ) * 10 + 5? Same idea, but the base is variable.

Comment: This solution, like yours, assumes you know the length of the whole. (It would require another 4 bits to not need that.)

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the length of the whole numerical string? i.e., `901418`